# Как определить четные/нечетные строки таблицы?

Tags: html, css

Как определить четные/нечетные строки таблицы через `css`?
Чтобы стили строк чередовались.

Answer (score 3):

Почитайте про [псевдоклассы](http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child), там все предельно просто. В вашем случае - это псевдоклассы **:odd** и **:even**

Answer (score 1):

Если нужна кроссбраузерность, то имейте в виду, что :odd и :even относится к CSS3 и не поддерживается в IE ниже 9. А вообще, почитать про это можно [здесь](http://htmlbook.ru/css/nth-child)
Но можно использовать [selectivizr](http://selectivizr.com) в связке с jQuery или другим известным фреймворком.

Answer (score 1):

Вот есть хорошая статья на эту тему: [«Полосатые таблицы» средствами CSS](http://lysenka.net/web/6/).